# Need to getLineCount form before rendering TextView

Tags: android, android-listview, textview

I want to set the height of the TextView before rendering in the getview function in my adapter. The result in getLineCount is always 0...

```
public View getView(LayoutInflater inflater, View convertView)
{
    textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.text);
    textView.setText(strText);
    int height_in_pixels = textView.getLineCount() * textView.getLineHeight();// getLineCount is always 0
    textView.setHeight(height_in_pixels);
}
```

I was thinking also maybe to calculate the  number of characters in the `strText` and then setting my height depending on the number of characters..

Thanks for your help

Comment: The TextView does not know the actual number of lines until it has rendered the text so you have a typical hen-egg problem. You might try to use View.INVISIBLE, render it, run your code and then change the visibility to View.VISIBLE

Comment: How can I render it in the getView() function?

Answer (score 1):

Thats because internal layout is not been set ,you have to call it after internal layout has been built - you can for 
example post `runnable` after calling `setText()` - doing so you make sure 
the internal layout is built